# How MySQL Event schedule 29 february - Internal Logic of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks

I just wanted to know that **how MySQL event schedule 29 february** as I am using MySQL Event so I am finding all exception cases in MySQL event if anyone knows that please help me...

## CASE:

**While using MySQL Event If Recurrence is Date is 29 february then how MySQL Handles it?**

```
$this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");
$this->db->query("CREATE EVENT rec".$id." ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH
STARTS DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '0:01' HOUR_MINUTE) 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO $str");
```

Above code creates my event but what if it will created on 29th feb?

How MySQL Event Will Handle it...??

Thank You...

Comment: MySQL will only create an event for 29th February if that event takes place in a leap year.... you could as easily ask what if it tries to create an event on 31st April: it won't, it knows how many days there are in each month of the year (even in leap years)

Comment: @Mark then how it will execute on next month i mean if event created on 30th Jan then when it will execute next time...??After 30 days or 1 month..So when next month will come........

Comment: what is the internal logic of MySQL event....for 29th Feb

Comment: The same as the internal logic behind `SELECT DATE_ADD('2016-01-30', INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`, it'll give the last day of February

Comment: @MarkBaker - But what will happen when the Event fires for 1 month later?  Will it be Mar 29 (or 28)?  And never get back to the 30th?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it and see.... you clearly have so little faith in the developers of MySQL, and assume that they haven't written it correctly.... I really think somebody somewhere in the world would have pointed it out to them before now if they'd got it wrong